# hadoop fs -ls : Call From server/127.0.1.1 to localhost failed

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have `hadoop` installed in pseudo-distributed mode.

When running the command

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ls: Call From kali/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception:
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
  For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you start your dfs? and checked /etc/hosts file?

Comment: @Y.Prithvi ,yes i started dfs using start-dfs.sh but it has no problem

Comment: @Y.Prithvi if you need any detail to solve this problem, tell me the required detail but help me !!!

Comment: what are the steps you followed?

Comment: i followed the following link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm

Comment: Java 7 is end of life and Hadoop 2.4 is not the latest, stable version, so that page is outdated. You need remove `127.0.1.1` lines from your /etc/hosts file and don't run HDFS using localhost if it is running in distributed mode

Comment: @YashBhatia Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @Y.Prithvi nope bro, i am unable to resolve the issue, i need help!!!

Comment: @cricket_007 I have currently installed hadoop 3.1.0 on my system and the openjdk version is 10.0.2

Comment: Last time I checked, Hadoop doesn't support Java 9 or above. The latest Java 8 runs fine, and is supported by the major Hadoop vendors. Additional, the vendors are still on Hadoop 3.0.x... If you want to try the latest version, you're more than welcome to, but most installation documentation on the internet is still (at least) Hadoop 2.6, which should work up to Hadoop 2.9, but 3.0 changed enough of the variable names that it might be work outside of following the official documentation

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks!!! that means i should now reinstall my java and hadoop,

Comment: 127.0.1.1 is unnecessary for Hadoop and generally causes conflicts with your external DNS provider and how Hadoop resolves external services. `sudo vi /etc/hosts` and remove that IP

Comment: Also, `hdfs://kali:9000` should be in your core-site.xml, not `localhost`

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks man !!! you help worked as water worked for a parched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the link in the error, I see two immediate points that need addressed.

> If the error message says the remote service is on "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" that means the configuration file is telling the client that the service is on the local server. If your client is trying to talk to a remote system, then your configuration is broken.

You should treat pseudodistributed mode *as a remote system*, even if it is only running locally.

For HDFS, you can resolve that by putting your computer hostname (preferably the full FQDN for your domain), as the HDFS address in core-site.xml. For your case, `hdfs://kali:9000` should be enough

> Check that there isn't an entry for your hostname mapped to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 in `/etc/hosts` (Ubuntu is notorious for this).

I'm not completely sure why it needs removed, but the general answer I can think of is that Hadoop is a distributed system, and as I mentioned, treat the pseudodistributed mode as if it's remote HDFS server. Therefore, no loopback addresses should use your computers hostname

For example, remove the second line of this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 kali
```

Or remove the hostname from this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost kali
```

Most importantly (emphasis added)

> None of these are Hadoop problems, they are hadoop, host, network **and** firewall configuration issues

Comment: Thanks ver much!  I forget to correct the 127.0.1.1 to localhost, so running job can't connect to some service correctly. Now it fixed!

Comment: Well, you don't really need 127.0.1.1, as mentioned. The hostname for each machine should resolve to an external LAN IP